# GCP cloud function deploy via CLI fails. Failed to retrieve function source code error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm just wondering if anyone else had a similar experience.

I will spare all details here for the sake of clarity. For context, I am trying to do the following:

- Write some python script meant to be executed via trigger (HTTP)
- During the Jenkins pipeline, execute a shell script that zips the aforementioned python script, and then deploys a cloud function via `gcloud function deploy ...`

However, I am noticing that, when executing the `gcloud function deploy ...` via CLI via Jenkins, I am getting the error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Failed to retrieve function source code
```

Assume that the bucket location of the source code is correct and that I zipped the code correctly (`zip -r <name of code>.zip .`). Here is the shell command I am running:

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT=<service account name>

gcloud functions deploy "<cloud function name>" \
  --project=<project_id> \
  --source=gs://<bucket name>/<name of code>.zip\
  --service-account=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
  --trigger-http \
  --ingress-settings="all" \
  --timeout=180s \
  --runtime="python38" \
  --entry-point="<name of my main method>" \
  --region="us-west1" \
  --memory="256"
```

I have obviously redacted some of these fields, this is for privacy purposes.

Now the main issue is this, when I run this command via Cloud Shell, I get the following:

`Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...done.`

Indicating that this is done successfully.

However, when I run this exact shell script in a Jenkins pipeline, this returns the above error first mentioned.

For reference, here is my Jenkinsfile that executes this shell script:

```
def MAIN_BRANCH = 'main'

pipeline {
    parameters {
        string(name: 'PROJECT_ID',
              defaultValue: '<project_id>',
              description: 'GCP Project')
    }
    environment {
        VERSION = "${env.GIT_COMMIT.take(7)}"
    }
    agent {
        label "${env.DOCKER_AGENT_LABEL}"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Mapping the Project ID') {
            steps {
                  script {
                      env.PROJECT_ID = params.PROJECT_ID
                      env.REGISTRY = "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}"
                  }
            }
        }
        stage('Upload content to GCS') {
            when {
                anyOf {
                   branch "${MAIN_BRANCH}"
                   branch ""
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh "gcloud config set project ${params.PROJECT_ID}" 
                sh "./scripts/gcp-cloud-function-code-upload.sh"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        cleanup {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

TLDR: I have a shell script that deploys a cloud function via CLI. When I run this script using Cloud Shell on GCP console, it succeeds in deploying the function. When I run this script in a Jenkins pipeline (where the service account executing the GCP-specific actions in Jenkins pipeline seemingly has sufficient IAM roles/permissions), the same shell script can't seem to read the source code. I'm not sure where the error may be on my side.

*Edit 1:* Just adding some more details. My github repository looks something like the following:

```
Root
   ---> scripts
       ---> gcp-cloud-function-code-upload.sh
   ---> <name of function>
       ---> <name of code>.py
       ---> requirements.txt
```

This would be important because I am invoking the shell script via a Jenkins pipeline (i.e. a commit in the main branch leads to the pipeline executing). This is addressing guillaume blaquiere's suggestion of checking the path where the shell script is executed.

*Edit 2*

I think this may be a network issue. The Jenkins agent that is executing the pipeline is in a different VPC network than the project in which we are looking to raise the Cloud Function. The firewall rule for our project's VPC network may be stopping the Jenkins agent from communicating with the project. I will update further at a later time.

Comment: "I would post more explicit code that I wrote, but I have followed every piece of documentation and checked every input possible." It would still be very, very useful to have a [mcve]. Just a "hello world" function, but with all the steps for zipping and the deployment comment. Are you able to successfully deploy the zipped source code outside Jenkins?

Comment: First of all, I often though Google Cloud Services were buggy, and most of the time it was me (Google is not invincible, but, I'm weaker!) Anyway. In your context, the Jenkins code is required because your issue let me think you are running the gcloud command in the wrong directory (and that's why you have this error).

Comment: @JonSkeet Apologies for the vague initial post. I have edited it with my shell script + Jenkinsfile and explained what I did that worked (executing on Cloud Shell), and where there is a discrepancy between executing the shell command via Jenkins pipeline vs Cloud Shell.

Comment: @JonSkeet On your last question, I am able to deploy the zipped source code successfully when I execute the exact shell script (that deploys a cloud function) on GCP console's Cloud Shell as opposed to in my Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I definitely agree with you on the first point (= If I had to wager my life on whether Google or I am wrong, I will side with Google 999/1000 times xD. I will take another look at the place in my Jenkinsfile where the shell command is executed. I will run pwd in my Jenkins pipeline to see where the current working directory is. I will return with any updates. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I am removing my close vote because you have updated the question with details.